# Singular / Plural

Tags: grammatical-number

I read this sentence in an English textbook: 
'Men's work finish at the office, but women's work is extended to their households.' 
Is the first clause grammatically correct, or it should be 'Men's work FINISHES at the office...'
Thank you.

Comment: Men's work is singular; hence it should be 'finishes'. Whether or not 'plurality' needs to be assigned in its use depends on the context.

Comment: @RamPillai: I agree with your first sentence, but I can't understand your second sentence at all.

Comment: @TonyK: I was referring to some such nouns that can be used as singular and plural as well, depending on situation(s), but of course, 'work' is a singular noun.

Comment: Another bad English textbook. Get one with a good editor, if possible.